# Timeout Exception in Weblogic 10 EJB Commit

Tags: hibernate, timeout, weblogic, jta, xa

I've got an issue in weblogic 10 / jre6 / hibernate 3.6.10 when it tries to commit the transaction. Could you please help me ?

I only have this stack in AdminServer_xxx.log:

```
####<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1570440458465> <BEA-010026> <Exception occurred during commit of transaction Name=[EJB myService.v2.connecteur.connecteurJavaBean.executerService(java.lang.String)],Xid=BEA1-00022F8C16F0D799C74D(22622538),Status=Rolling Back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Timed out tx=BEA1-00022F8C16F0D799C74D after 300 seconds],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=424,seconds left=60,XAServerResourceInfo[xxx]=(ServerResourceInfo[xxx]=(state=rolledback,assigned=AdminServer_xxx),xar=xxx,re-Registered = false),XAServerResourceInfo[DsOracle_xxx]=(ServerResourceInfo[DsOracle_xxx]=(state=rolledback,assigned=AdminServer_xxx),xar=DsOracle_xxx,re-Registered = false),NonXAServerResourceInfo[WL_JDBC_LLR_POOL.DsOracle_xxx]=(ServerResourceInfo[WL_JDBC_LLR_POOL.DsOracle_xxx]=(state=rolledback,assigned=AdminServer_xxx),nonXAResource=JDBC LLR, pool=DsOracle_xxx, table=ORUSER.WL_LLR_ADMINSERVER_XXX),SCInfo[xxx]=(state=rolledback),SCInfo[LDBUS+Sync96jp-x91]=(state=rolling-back),properties=({weblogic.transaction.nonXAResource=WL_JDBC_LLR_POOL.DsOracle_xxx, weblogic.jdbc.remote.DsOracle_xxx=t3://x.x.x.x:9003, weblogic.transaction.name=[EJB myService.v2.connecteur.connecteurJavaBean.executerService(java.lang.String)], weblogic.jdbc.llr=DsOracle_xxx}),local properties=({weblogic.jdbc.jta.DsOracle_xxx=[ No XAConnection is attached to this TxInfo ], weblogic.jdbc.jta.xxx=[ No XAConnection is attached to this TxInfo ]}),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=AdminServer_xxx+x.x.x.x:9003+XXX+t3+, XAResources={dsTxS4_FF_SI_StreamAnt, DsOracle_da042_XA_FF_SI_StreamAnt, xxx, xxx},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=xxx+x.x.x.x:9003+xxx+t3+): weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Timed out tx=BEA1-00022F8C16F0D799C74D after 300 seconds
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:1884)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:376)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:267)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.postInvoke1(BaseRemoteObject.java:625)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessRemoteObject.postInvoke1(StatelessRemoteObject.java:49)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseRemoteObject.java:444)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:53)
    at myService.v2.connecteur.connecteur_AAA_tpyl5k_EOImpl.executerService(Unknown Source)
    at myService.v2.connecteur.connecteur_AAA_tpyl5k_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Timed out tx=BEA1-00022F8C16F0D799C74D after 300 seconds
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1879)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.processTimedOutTransactions(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1706)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(TransactionManagerImpl.java:1988)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1616)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.WLSTimer.timerExpired(WLSTimer.java:35)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:284)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    ... 2 more
```

I imagine it could be a bad configuration of datasource:

```
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source/1.2/jdbc-data-source.xsd">
  <name>DsOracle_XXX</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/XE</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>user</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <password-encrypted>pwd</password-encrypted>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
  <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <test-table-name>SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</test-table-name>
  </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
  <jdbc-data-source-params>
    <jndi-name>DsOracle_XXX</jndi-name>
    <global-transactions-protocol>TwoPhaseCommit</global-transactions-protocol>
  </jdbc-data-source-params>
  <jdbc-xa-params>
    <keep-xa-conn-till-tx-complete>false</keep-xa-conn-till-tx-complete>
    <xa-set-transaction-timeout>true</xa-set-transaction-timeout>
    <xa-transaction-timeout>0</xa-transaction-timeout>
    <rollback-local-tx-upon-conn-close>false</rollback-local-tx-upon-conn-close>
  </jdbc-xa-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

Or in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.datasource">DsOracle_XXX</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">jta</property>
        <property name="query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <mapping resource="persistance/hibernate/mapping/xxx.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thank you for your help,
NicoS.

Comment: The exception is raised because the transaction has excedeed the JTA timeout configured in your domain (300 seconds) You should take several thread dumps during your test to see where the time is spent in your code.

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel, I already tried to do thread-dumps but I don't find any thread blocked or any deadlock..

Comment: you may find at least one long running thread working on the same request for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the solution in the datasource configuration.

Thank you Emmanuel for your help.

Here is the working configuration :

```
  <jdbc-xa-params>
    <keep-xa-conn-till-tx-complete>true</keep-xa-conn-till-tx-complete>
    <keep-logical-conn-open-on-release>false</keep-logical-conn-open-on-release>
    <resource-health-monitoring>true</resource-health-monitoring>
    <xa-set-transaction-timeout>true</xa-set-transaction-timeout>
    <xa-transaction-timeout>0</xa-transaction-timeout>
    <rollback-local-tx-upon-conn-close>true</rollback-local-tx-upon-conn-close>
  </jdbc-xa-params>
```

I hope it will helps other people :)

Regards,
NicoS